# Using freezegun, why do pytz.utc and utcnow() output different datetimes?

Tags: python, datetime, pytz, freezegun

I'm puzzled why a function that freezes time with freezegun outputs different UTC times depending on whether `datetime.datetime.utcnow()` is called, or `datetime.datetime.now(pytz.utc)`. I'm not saying it's broken, just that I don't understand why, and would like to know!

eg, using this function:

```
@freeze_time("2012-01-14 03:21:34", tz_offset=-4)
def test():
    print("utcnow(): %s" % datetime.datetime.utcnow())
    print("pytz.utc: %s" % datetime.datetime.now(pytz.utc))
```

the output is:

```
utcnow(): 2012-01-14 03:21:34
pytz.utc: 2012-01-13 23:21:34+00:00
```

I guess the first is a naive datetime, but why are they different times?

(Ultimately why I want to know: if I'm using freezegun in my tests, and I use pytz to generate times in my code being tested, I want to know what its 'correct' behaviour should be.)

Comment: Isn't that correct considering  `tz_offset=-4` ? One is aware the other is naive

Comment: I don't know, that's why I'm asking :) I assumed that given you can set a timezone offset with freezegun, and you're asking for UTC from each, that they would both have the same time. Even if only one had the timezone attached.

Comment: I mean, if you output `datetime.datetime.now()` in that function you get `2012-01-13 23:21:34`. Is freezegun freezing the time to 2012-01-14 03:21 UTC or 2012-01-13 23:21 UTC?

Comment: Using now the date and time  are converted to the tz‘s time zone. utcnow is gmt

Comment: So you're saying: freezegun is setting the time to 2012-01-14 03:21 UTC, and timezone to -4 hrs. `datetime.datetime.now()` is the local time (ie, 2012-01-13 23:21) and I'm artificially forcing that time to have UTC timezone info?

Comment: Yes `2012-01-13 23:21)` is the local time, it is also shown in the docs under timezones https://github.com/spulec/freezegun although the assert would fail for datetime.today because the time is not in datetime.today so it would be `00:00:00` for `datetime.datetime(2012, 01, 13)`. If you use `assert datetime.date.today() == datetime.datetime(2012, 01, 13).date()` it should pass

Comment: No worries, datetimes can be confusing at the best of times, the fact the assertion fails in the docs would not help.

Comment: [According to the docs](https://github.com/spulec/freezegun#timezones), the 2nd one should show: `2012-01-14 03:21:34+00:00`. `23:21:34+00:00` looks like a bug.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, why should it be `03:21:34+00:00`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: what is unclear? Do you understand that `utcnow() == now(pytz.utc).replace(tzinfo=None)`?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian,I thought you were referring to the example in the docs, so basically in the OPs code   `pytz.utc` is being ignored?

Comment: I *think* that applying `pytz.utc` like that doesn't affect the calculation of the time value - it simply takes the time that `now()` generated and gives it the UTC timezone, without actually *changing* the time. I may be wrong, but that's what I'm assuming is happening. So the docs are correct.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: click the link in my comment: it shows the example from the docs that asserts that `utcnow() == 03:21:34` and therefore `now(pytz.utc)` must be `03:21:34+00:00`.

Answer (score 5):

This is an issue within freezegun see [here](https://github.com/spulec/freezegun/issues/179) and [here](https://github.com/spulec/freezegun/issues/89).

It does not look like that this will be fixed soon. In the end I used this as a workaround:

```
def freezegun_utc_workaround():
    return datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)
```

For this

```
 datetime.datetime.now(pytz.utc)
```

May be it is even better to wrap this and patch it manually.

Comment: How did you use this? Can you include a full code sample?

Comment: Replace all occurances of "datetime.datetime.now(pytz.utc)" with "freezegun_utc_workaround()". After that use "patch" from "unittest.mock" to make "freezegun_utc_workaround" return whatever you desire.